# JPQL: How to join via @ElementCollection with @MapKeyJoinColumn

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have problems creating the correct JPQL query for joining through the following tables:

[image]

While between GROUPS and USERS there is a conventional @ManyToMany mapping table, *DOCUMENTS_GROUPS* is what causes the trouble. As you can see in the following entity, I want the relationship between *DOCUMENTS* and *GROUPS* to be mapped as a Map containing the *access_mode* (which works just fine except for the query):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENTS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "Documents.findAccessibleByUser",
        query = "SELECT d FROM Document d INNER JOIN d.groups g INNER JOIN KEY(g).members m WHERE m.id = :userId"
    )
})
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "DOCUMENTS_GROUPS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "document_id")})
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    @Column(name = "access_mode")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<Group, AccessMode> groups = new HashMap<>();

    /* ... */

}
```

With Group being rather normal:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_GROUPS", //
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")}, //
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")} //
    )
    private Set<User> members = new HashSet<>();

    /* ... */

}
```

---

My question is now: How do I need to modify the second JOIN in my JPQL query?

```sql
SELECT d FROM Document d
  INNER JOIN d.groups g
  INNER JOIN KEY(g).members m
WHERE m.id = :userId
```

is syntactically wrong (unexpected `KEY` after `INNER JOIN`).

Of course, I have already tried a plain `INNER JOIN g.members m`, but since we're dealing with a `Map<Group, AccessMode>`, this fails with `cannot dereference scalar collection element: members`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with a simple key-value `Map<String, String>` like:

`@Entity` *Item.java*

```java
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
@Column(name = "value")
@CollectionTable(indexes = @Index(columnList = "value"))
private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

Joining the attributes was possible:

```java
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i INNER JOIN i.attributes attr");
```

but **not** querying fields:

```java
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i INNER JOIN i.attributes attr WHERE attr.value = 'something'");
```

I debugged the Hibernate internals and found out that the alias `attr` is already resolved to the value (`e.attributes.value`), so the only thing you can do here is:

```java
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i INNER JOIN i.attributes attr WHERE attr = 'something'");
```

But I did not find any documentation or JPQL examples pointing that out. The behaviour is  is useless in my case, because I want to have conditions for both key and value. Thats why I migrated to a foreign entity collection with key mapping and composite primary key. Its way more complicated but works as expected.

The composite key entity to prevent single primary keys

```java
@Embeddable
public class ItemAttributeName implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Item item;

    // Empty default constructor is important
    public ItemAttributeName() {

    }

    public ItemAttributeName(Item item, String name) {
        this.item = article;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The real attribute entity

```java
@Entity
public class ItemAttribute {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemAttributeName id;

    private String value;

    // Empty default constructor is important
    public ItemAttribute() {

    }

   
    public ItemAttribute(Item item, String name) {
        this.id = new ItemAttributeName (item, name);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

`@Entity` *Item.java*

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.item",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
public Map<String, ItemAttribute> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

Creating entities:

```java
Item item = new Item ();
ItemAttribute fooAttribute = new ItemAttribute(item, "foo");
fooAttribute.setValue("356");
item.attributes.put("foo", fooAttribute);
```

Querying entities:

```java
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i JOIN i.attributes attr WHERE attr.id.name = 'foo' AND attr.value='bar'");
List<Item> resultList = query.getResultList();
System.out.println(resultList.get(0).attributes.get("foo").getValue());
```

Prints out: *bar*